# On-Click Button: Why is Salesforce passing in 'undefined' string value?

Tags: custom-button, list-view, onclick, list-button

I am trying to auto-insert an array of Tasks based on the Accounts selected in the Account 'List View' tab.

The tasks are inserting as expected, but instead of writing the Account Name in the subject line, actual result is

> Followup with undefined - Assigned [Today's Date]

I tried just using {!Account.Name} and no value was passed through there at all.

Relevant code block:

```
for (var i = 0; i < accountIds.length; i++) { 
        var taskToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Task");
        taskToCreate.WhatId = accountIds[i];     
        taskToCreate.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
        taskToCreate.Subject = "Followup with " + accountIds[i].Name + " - Assigned {!TODAY()}";
        taskToCreate.ActivityDate = dueDate;            

        taskToCreate.Priority = "Normal";
        taskToCreate.Status = "Not Started";

        assignedTasks.push(taskToCreate);
}
```

How can I pass in the looped through Account's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetRecordIds formula literally does what it says: it gets the list of Id values the user selected. If you want the account names, you have to use sforce.connection.retrieve or sforce.connection.query to get those values. You'll want to read the Ajax Toolkit developer's guide for more details.

Here's an example using your code as a base:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js")}

var accountIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Account)};

var accounts = sforce.connection.retrieve("Id,Name","Account",accountIds);
var tasks = [];
var dueDate = /* calculate due date here */ new Date();
accounts.forEach(function(account) {
  var task = new sforce.SObject("Task");
  task.WhatId = account.Id;
  task.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
  task.Subject = "Follow-Up With "+account.Name+" - Assigned {!TODAY()}";
  task.ActivityDate = dueDate;
  task.Priority = "Normal";
  task.Status = "Not Started";
  tasks.push(task);
});
var results = sforce.connection.create(tasks);
```

Make sure you do basic error checking, and you should be okay.

Comment: Thank you! I will start digging, looking forward to your edits

Comment: @GPP As promised, a code sample for you to look at. This more or less works verbatim in my developer org (tested it before I added it here), but of course you'll want to add error checking.

Comment: Thank you! I do actually have Error checking located below the code block I pasted. Out of curiosity, is the `{!GETRECORDIDS}` function even necessary at this point? It looks like all the variable arrays storing those values were deprecated

Comment: @GPP accountIds is used in sforce.connecton.retrieve, so you still use GETRECORDIDS to determine which records to create tasks for.

Comment: yep was just about to reply! This is awesome, thank you. Out of curiosity, why did you define the `var results` variable? I did not have to initialize `result` in my earlier code and I was able to get to run time.

Comment: @GPP By not defining a variable, you're [polluting the global namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665). This is effectively a memory leak. While nothing bad would likely happen, you take a risk every time you dump something into the global namespace, so you should get in the habit of not doing it.

Comment: Is `result` a global variable referenced in the `{!REQUIRESCRIPT}` function? Is that why you created your own local variable `var results` instead?

Comment: @GPP The point of using var is to make sure your data doesn't go out to the global scope. Just avoid creating global variables arbitrarily, and you'll be okay. RequireScript only imports some source code and generally produces very little pollution (just sforce.connection is created). It's really just easier to say: "when in doubt, declare a local variable.". There's some exceptions to the rule, but you'll find them necessary when you  Usually, you ant privacy party of friends